# POST data faild using http.NewRequest

Tags: forms, go, http-headers, microservices, distributed-tracing

I am trying to pass data from one golang service to another using `http.NewRequest()`. To do it I used following code:

```
        httpClient := http.Client{}

        userserviceUrl := "http://user:7071/checkemail"

        form := url.Values{}
        form.Set("uuid", uuid)
        form.Set("email", email)

        b := bytes.NewBufferString(form.Encode())
        req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", userserviceUrl, b)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        opentracing.GlobalTracer().Inject(
            validateEmailSpan.Context(),
            opentracing.HTTPHeaders,
            opentracing.HTTPHeadersCarrier(req.Header))

        resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
        //_, err = http.PostForm("http://user:7071/checkemail", url.Values{"uuid": {uuid}, "email": {email}})

        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Couldnt verify email address user service sends an error : ", err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
```

I got this from [Golang: http.NewRequest POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624969/golang-http-newrequest-post-with-json-payload-returns-error-500)

When I try to dump received data from user service:

```
    req.ParseForm()
    log.Println("Form values : ", req.Form)
```

I get an empty `map[]`

Here I just try to inject tracing span to my request, previously I have used `http.PostForm()` to pass data, it worked perfectly. But I have [no idea to pass `tracing` to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58672447/distributed-tracing-with-golang-http-postform).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the docs for ParseForm](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm):

> [...] when the Content-Type is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the request Body is not read, and r.PostForm is initialized to a non-nil, empty value.

PostForm sets the Content-Type automatically, but now you have to do it yourself:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", userserviceUrl, strings.NewReader(form.Encode()))
// TODO: handle error
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Comment: what I have missed `req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`.